# how to click or select each option in dropdown menu with Cypress

Tags: cypress

I want to iterate through all options that exists in a dropdown menu and be able to click or select one option per iteration. The options are created from server response so the amount of options in the menu are not always the same.

Here is the HTML code for the dropdown menu:

```
<select id="filter1" class="form-control abc">
<option value="" selected="selected">text1</option>
<option value="text2">text2</option>
<option value="text3">text3</option><!----></select>
```

This is my code for cypress:

```
        cy.wait(2000).get('#filter1').each(($el, index) => {
            cy.log("loop index: " + index)
            cy.wrap($el).select(index)
        })
```

I get a TypeError in the console:
v.replace is not a function

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: please add the html for your dropdown menu.

Comment: Now I edited my post and the html code is added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where and how you use call this `.replace` method, you gotta look for that elsewhere, but this will do what you want with the example you provided:

```
cy.wait(2000).get('#filter1 option').each(($el, index) => {
   cy.log("loop index: " + index)
   cy.get('#filter1').select(index)
})
```

Comment: I tried your code but still the same error occurs.

Comment: now I realize the looping works after deleting the last line that runs the select(). But when I allow the select() to run then I get this on the console:  -select:      0

Comment: That makes sense since, first index starts at 0. Make sure that your select in first .get command points to `option` tags, and not `select` tag as the options are the ones you want to loop.

Comment: Okay. But how can I make it to select an option without knowing the text within the option? I tried to use select(index) but it gives the error. According to a website it's not meant to work with selecting index.

Comment: It worked for me if when I created a simple `test.html` file in the root folder with the same content you provided above, used `cy.visit('./test.html')` to load it and ran the command I provided. I can see everything works as expected, all the options were selected one by one in a loop. Your error gotta originate elsewhere.
And select does work with indexes, as specified in the official documentation here: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/select#Arguments

Comment: I see. I found a solution for the second part of the "problem", I used this: `cy.get('#filter1').select($el.text())`
However you solved my first part of the problem so I accept your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `.get()` could be chained off [`.wait()` with a time argument](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait#Arguments):

> When given a time argument:
>
> cy.wait() yields the same subject it was given from the previous command.

[`cy.get()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get#Rules) requires being chained off a command that yields a DOM element:

> cy.get() requires being chained off a command that yields DOM element(s).

Comment: That bit of the docs is a bit dubious. See also [get vs find](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get#Get-vs-Find) *The cy.get command always starts its search from the cy.root element...*, so if you chain two `get()` the 2nd one does not search from the element yielded by the first.